# Liquid output inside css.liquid file doesn't work?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to include a css.liquid file with a :root{} and different css variables to my theme.liquid.

Inside the css.liquid file I have multiple variables and liquid outputs. Example:

```
:root {
  --color-1: rgba({{ settings.color_scheme.settings.color1.rgba }});
  --color-2: rgba({{ settings.color_scheme.settings.color2.rgba }});
  ... more variables
}
```

When I include the file in the theme.liquid I get this (the color values are not there):

```
:root {
  --color-1:
  --color-2:
  ... more variables
}
```

When I output the color anywhere in the body it works perfectly and I get the color value {{ settings.color_scheme.settings.color2.rgba }}.

I don't know what the error is?

I tried to output the variables in the body tag and it works flawlessly...

Comment: same problem, it seems it used to work and it stopped. Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was not able to fix it. I now use a liquid snippet for it.